# Reading int values into a array is not working as expected

Tags: c

I have written following code to read some int values in to an array and find the greatest of them.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()   {

    int a[5] ;
    int i ;
    int Gr = 0 ;
    int j ;


    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++ )  {
        scanf( "%d" , &a[i] ) ;
    }


    for ( j = 0 ; j <= 5 ; j++ ) {

        if ( a[j] > Gr)  {
            Gr = a[j] ;
        }   

    }

    printf("%d\n" , Gr ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

I observed that if for numbers `1 and 2` , No matter how many times I enter it does not stop loop and prints the highest.

Why is it happening?

Comment: You're reading six values into an array that only has space for five, and in the process invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: What if the user enters all the values that are less than `0`? How will your program come up with the maximum one? For this purpose, you should initialize the variable `Gr` with the minimum value that an `int` can store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++ )
```

is wrong, it will read 6 numbers and overflow `a`, triggering undefined behavior (perhaps even overwriting `i`). It should be:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
```

You should almost always use the pattern `for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)` when plain iterating over `N` items in an array.

For this particular code, it's not a good idea to repeat the `5`, that's a magic constant. Use `sizeof` to compute it at compile-time:

```
for( i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++ )
```

should be

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
```